# Expect call in GMock with Factory returning unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, factory-pattern, googlemock

I have factory that creates some windows by returning unique_ptr:

```
std::unique_ptr<WindowsInterface> NCursesWindowsFactory::createMainWindow()
{
    return std::make_unique<NCursesMainWindowDecorator>(std::make_unique<NCursesWindow>());
}
```

And in Mocked factory class this method:

```
MOCK_METHOD0(createMainWindow, std::unique_ptr<WindowsInterface>());
```

How to write EXPECT_CALL that will return some object as unique_ptr without copying it, just as I do in my fist method?
My EXPECT_CALL on factory mock has return like this:

```
.WillOnce(Return(std::make_unique<NCursesMainWindowDecorator>(std::make_unique<NCursesWindow>())))
```

And I want to move this unique_ptr but gmock tries to copy that:

```
./lib/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:579:59: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = miniReader::windowsManager::WindowsInterface; _Dp = std::default_delete<miniReader::windowsManager::WindowsInterface>]’
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but here an option:

Just add 'ByMove' additional action to move the argument:

```
.WillOnce(Return(ByMove(std::make_unique<NCursesMainWindowDecorator>(std::make_unique<NCursesWindow>()))))
```